# Implicit declaration of function 'SecCertificateInferLabel' is invalid in C99

Tags: cocoa

The code (OS X Mountain Lion):

```
OSStatus statusNew = SecCertificateInferLabel(cert, &nameRef);
```

Produces a warning in subj, below you have all includes:

```
#import <SecurityInterface/SFChooseIdentityPanel.h>
#include <Security/cssmtype.h>
#include <Security/oidsalg.h>
#include <Security/SecCertificate.h>
#include <Security/SecIdentity.h>
#include <Security/SecIdentitySearch.h>
#include <Security/SecPolicySearch.h>
#include <Security/SecTrust.h>
#include <Security/SecIdentitySearch.h>
#include <Security/cssmapi.h>
#include <Security/cssmapple.h>
#include <Security/cssmtype.h>
#include <Security/Security.h>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Do any of those headers define `SecCertificateInferLabel`?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the [`SecCertificatePriv.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-38259/lib/SecCertificatePriv.h) header as well:

```
#include <Security/SecCertificatePriv.h>
```

I see that it includes the declaration for the function you want to use.

```
...
/*
 * Private API to infer a display name for a SecCertificateRef which
 * may or may not be in a keychain.
 * This is a candidate for deprecation; use SecItemCopyDisplayNames() instead.
 */
OSStatus SecCertificateInferLabel(SecCertificateRef certificate, CFStringRef *label);
...
```

Comment: i was try to do this, but i receive file not found!

Comment: I'm trying to `#include <Security/SecCertificatePriv.h>` but I get the error: `fatal error: 'Security/SecCertificatePriv.h' file not found`